# Space Error in Intelliji IDE - Intellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor - Low disk space on a IntelliJ IDEA system directory partition

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Due to low running memory - Intelliji is consistently throwing a pop up error

> "low disk space error in intelliJ IDE."(repeatedly)

Version - IntelliJ Idea Community version 14

Tried few suggestions from the official site
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/tuning-intellij-idea.html

None of the size increasing techniques solved this particular error.
(Note - There are 100+ GB of free space the intelliji installed partition.)

Also tried a solution suggested in a forum - to add parameter -Didea.no.system.path.space.monitoring=true in
/bin/idea.vmoptions file(located inside < intelliJ installed directory >) and restarted intelliJ,

But issue still persists. Any suggestions is most welcomed.

Comment: It is entirely clear what is being asked here.  I am not sure why this question was closed.

Comment: (After return was interpreted as comment done and "comments can only be edited for 5 minutes" issue, just completing in a separate comment)

From the "How to ask" page:
Search, and research -> Done
Write a title that summarizes the specific problem -> Done
Introduce the problem before you post any code -> Done
Help others reproduce the problem -> Not relevant
Include all relevant tags -> Done
Proof-read before posting! -> Apparently done?
Post the question and respond to feedback -> Not relevant
Look for help asking for help -> Doesn't seem relevant at first glance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its resolved after adding this parameter - idea.no.system.path.space.monitoring=true in /bin/idea.properties file.

Source - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118718

Comment: I suspect this relates to:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055062

I saw this on server 2012 matching the jdk bug environment.